Read grayscale image from folder
In this my code I read grayscale images from two folders "hr" and "lr". why when I display the images the resulted images like green image not gray? what is the issue in my code?
How can read the images as gray and then show them as gray?
============================================================================================================================================================================================================
This is the resulted image:

from skimage import io, transform
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob

def sample_images(data_dir, batch_size, high_resolution_shape, low_resolution_shape):
    hr_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'hr')  # Path to HR image folder
    lr_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'lr')  # Path to LR image folder

    # Creating list of all images in HR and LR directories
    hr_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(hr_dir, '*.*'))
    lr_images = glob.glob(os.path.join(lr_dir, '*.*'))

    # Choosing a random batch of images
    hr_images_batch = np.random.choice(hr_images, size=batch_size)
    lr_images_batch = np.random.choice(lr_images, size=batch_size)

    low_resolution_images = []
    high_resolution_images = []

    for hr_img, lr_img in zip(hr_images_batch, lr_images_batch):
        # Getting numpy ndarray of current HR image
        hr_img1 = io.imread(hr_img, as_gray=True)
       ### hr_img1 = np.repeat(hr_img1[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)

        # Resizing HR image
        hr_img1_high_resolution = transform.resize(hr_img1, high_resolution_shape, mode='constant')

        # Getting numpy ndarray of current LR image
        lr_img1 = io.imread(lr_img, as_gray=True)

        # Resizing LR image
        lr_img1_low_resolution = transform.resize(lr_img1, low_resolution_shape, mode='constant')

        # Applying augmentation: random horizontal flip
        if np.random.random() < 0.5:
            hr_img1_high_resolution = np.fliplr(hr_img1_high_resolution)
            lr_img1_low_resolution = np.fliplr(lr_img1_low_resolution)

        high_resolution_images.append(hr_img1_high_resolution)
        low_resolution_images.append(lr_img1_low_resolution)
    
    # Convert lists to numpy ndarrays
    return np.array(high_resolution_images), np.array(low_resolution_images)


data_dir = r'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\dataasets\\Newfolder\\data\\'
batch_size = 2
low_resolution_shape = (64, 64, 3)
high_resolution_shape = (256, 256, 3)

 # Sampling batch of images
high_resolution_images, low_resolution_images = sample_images(data_dir=data_dir, batch_size=batch_size,
                                                                          low_resolution_shape=low_resolution_shape,
                                                                          high_resolution_shape=high_resolution_shape)

# Displaying high-resolution images
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=batch_size, figsize=(12, 4))
for i in range(batch_size):
    axs[i].imshow(high_resolution_images[i])
    axs[i].axis('off')
plt.suptitle('High-Resolution Images')
plt.show()

# Displaying low-resolution images
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=batch_size, figsize=(12, 4))
for i in range(batch_size):
    axs[i].imshow(low_resolution_images[i])
    axs[i].axis('off')
plt.suptitle('Low-Resolution Images')
plt.show()


maybe it doesn't read it as gray. Gray image usually have last dimension 1 but I see 3 in some places in your code. Other idea: maybe matplotlib has problem to display it as gray.

python - Display image as grayscale - Stack Overflow
